# How do I set up an embedded report into a microsoft dynamics crm contact form?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011

I am a total newb to ms dynamics crm, I need to embed a ssrs report into a contact form, or come up with something close to it. I wrote the report and published it, but the client wants to see this within the form. So I need to know how to add this to the form, how to pass the client Id to it. The data comes from an extended table if that matters here. I have been reading up on how the crm works, but from a programming standpoint, I have no clue on how to do this, and it seems like a good amount of background is necessary up front. Can anyone point me to anything that can get this done? The client is getting very impatient. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can have an iFrame that points to the report viewer.  Here is a blog that explains how to do it, and even passes in the record ID to the report: [Link to the blog](http://mscrmshop.blogspot.com/2012/02/step-by-step-tutorial-to-add-crm-report.html).

Comment: Andy, does how I get the data matter? In the ssrs report, I don't pull any data based on the contact id, but rather all data and originally somehow the crm would filter this. In this case shouldn't that be changed?

Comment: Prefiltering should then work if you pass in the record id to the report viewer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328288.aspx.  That way the report would be unique per record.  If you don't want it to be unique then you can just create an iFrame that points directly to that report.

Comment: Andy, now I am stuck with not being able to build a vs project that can publish to the clients crm, is there a way to get that js file into the crm another way?

Comment: Andy, I figured this out, I did not know you could do this, thanks for your help.